# Mac preventing loading Java site

Tags: macos, security, java, nas

I am trying to administer my Western Digital MyBookLife home network drive, using the Java based admin console provided by WD. The console is a web application served up from the drive itself.

However, since I upgraded to Java 8, the Mac is preventing me from loading the page (a Java applet), which is on my network at `192.168.1.2`

I opened the Java console and added `http://192.168.1.2` to my trusted network site list, however it is still rejecting me.

The message says

```
Application Blocked by Java Security
Name: WDTester
Location http://192.168.1.2
Reason: Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running.
```

Also, I am getting another prompt that says again "Application Blocked by Java Security" but this time it says reason: Your security settings have blocked an application signed with an expired or not-yet-valid certificate from running

I see in the Java Control Panel the exception site list containing my host, as specified above (I also added the same with https protocol, and I also added localhost just to be sure.) But for some reason, it is ignoring the exceptions.

What to do??

Comment: what version is your WD MBL?

Comment: I don't know. I can't get in to the admin page, and it is not marked on the case. I am trying to upgrade the firmware, but it also requires the admin page

Comment: Have you tried the WD MY Cloud.app for Mac?  I don't believe it relies on Java.   http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=902&sid=184&lang=en

Comment: Are you using Safari ?? - if Yes, then try to set your local site to unsafe mode, as described here: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202819